# How to manage pipe ends for a shell in c

Tags: c, shell

I am trying to make a c-shell that supports pipes. So far it works until I try a command that involves a large file, in which case it fails. I assume this is because I am not able to handle more data than fits into a single pipe.

```
static int execute(Sequence* sequence) {
   pid_t pid;

   pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
      execvp(sequence->args[0], sequence->args);
   }
   else if (pid < 0) {
      perror("execute");
   }

   return pid;
}

int runCommands(Sequence* sequences, int seqSize) {
   /* sets up pipes for all processes but the last */
   for (i = 0; i < seqSize-1; i++) {
      /* pipe, store fds and execute */
   }

   /* execute last */

   /* wait for pids */

   return 0;
}
```

This is my Sequence structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int read;
    int write;
    char* arg[MAX_ARGS+1];
} Sequence;
```

I call runCommands with a correct sequence array in my main. When testing I've found that when I run it with something like "cat large_file | head -10", head terminates but cat does not.

Am I not closing the file descriptors correctly?

Comment: ...*again*? We must get this question in some form or another at least once a week. Have you tried searching for prior instances (and their answers)?

Comment: @Charles Duffy Yes I have. One of them was mine that you commented on but I was told it was not a good enough question by a peer so I deleted it. Hopefully, this reworded one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the normal problem — you are not closing anywhere near enough file descriptors.

If you have a 3-stage pipeline, you have two pipes, or four descriptors, open in the parent process before you begin forking — plus the original standard input and standard output.  When the first child forks, it closes 1 of the 4 pipe descriptors, the one that's connected to its standard output.  It leaves the other 3 open, which is a disaster.  The second child closes 2 of the 4 pipe descriptors but leaves the other 2 open.  The third child closes 1 of the 4 pipe descriptors.  Also, the parent process still has all the file descriptors open; it needs to close all the pipe descriptors too before it does any waiting.

Because the write end of the first pipe is still open in the last process, the second process doesn't get EOF on its standard input, so the code hangs with the second process waiting for input that will never arrive.

Even in a simple 2-stage pipeline, you run into the problem that the parent process has the write end of the pipe open.  (I think the second child also has the write end of the pipe open too, but the parent is sufficient to hang your code.)

You must close a lot more file descriptors!

You can see [Redirect stdout of two processes to another process's stdin in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041416/redirect-stdout-of-two-processes-to-another-processs-stdin-in-linux-c) and [Two forks and the use of wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654315/two-forks-and-the-use-of-wait) for two minor variations on a rule of thumb:

- **Rule of Thumb**: If you duplicate one end of a pipe to a process's standard input or standard output, you need to close *both* ends of the pipe in that process.

A search on SO for 'user:15168 [c] rule thumb pipe' turns up 10 other answers with this piece of information presented as a rule of thumb.  Of course, you need to know that's a good search; you wouldn't know that a priori.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I understand you, each time I fork, in my child I should close every file descriptor there is before I exec?

Comment: All the pipe file descriptors should be closed by each child (after duplicating to standard input and/or standard output as required).  And the parent also needs to close all the pipe file descriptors too.  Also, if you're brave, the POSIX specification for [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) says that if you try to duplicate file descriptor N to itself, nothing goes wrong, so you could simply duplicate without testing for standard input and standard output.  Whether that's truly a good idea is more debatable — but even POSIX 1990 required it.