# C Minishell - Need to Kill Zombies for Pipeline Implementation

Tags: c, shell, unix, parent-child, wait

So I'm building a minishell in C(for unix). I just figured out how to get pipelines to work, however I'm having a Zombie problem. Let's say I have:

```
echo a | echo b | echo c
```

This doesn't output anything, when it should be outputting "c". However, if I tell my shell to execute each sub-command, and then wait before moving on to the next command, it works fine. However this isn't a real solution, as I want that natural coordination between pipes that you get if you don't wait.

I'm having trouble devising an efficient way to wait on all the zombies once the last command is executed. I tried doing this after the last execution, but before the shell exits:

```
while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
```

However, no luck. So far the only thing that works is by telling my shell to execute each sub-command, and then wait before starting the next command. Here's the entire main shell file:

http://pastebin.com/YV96mFy7

The main function that processes input(processline()) starts at line 105.

Thanks for the help, if you guys need anything more just ask.

Comment: Do you know what that `WNOHANG` supposed to do? Yes. This is wrong. You should either (a) trap the SIGCHLD and wait there. or (b) know how many child you have, wait exactly that much without WNOHANG.

Comment: Ohh, how do I catch the SIGCHLD? Do I simply make a handler in the parent, that then waits when it gets a SIGCHLD? If so, what does WNOHANG have to do with it? Thanks :)

Comment: You can't afford to wait for process 1 to complete before launching process 2 in general.  You might find some help at [C Minishell — Adding Pipelines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13640308/15168).

Comment: That's my post, haha, I just did it on the second account. I see you added more stuff, I'll go take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
```

To:

```
while(wait(NULL) > 0);

/* which is equivalent to */
while(waitpid(-1, NULL, 0) > 0);
```

This will cause the parent process to wait for all child processes to finish, if you don't wish to block the parent process then catch `SIGCHLD` and call `wait()` in the signal handler instead.

Comment: You don't mean what you said, I think.  Were you intending to use plain `wait()` in the second loop?  `waitpid()` needs three arguments, but `waitpid(-1, 0, 0)` would be the same as `wait(0)`, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes that's exactly what I meant, I copied the line and forgot to change it to `wait`, thanks.