# pipe in C stuck when calling `wc` or `grep`

Tags: c, pipe, fork, wait

Problem - when calling `ls -l | grep etc`, stuck on grep (`grep` child process does not exit)

[trying to run "ls | grep r" with "execvp()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693446/trying-to-run-ls-grep-r-with-execvp) suggests that

- need to close file descriptors
- wait outside of the forking loop

IMO I have performed both of above but the problem still exists.

Any opinion is welcome, thanks!

Note that below is a hard-coded version for 2 pipes only

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int pfd[2];
    if (pipe(pfd) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error creating pipe\n");
        exit(errno);
    }
    char **ptr = get_pipes(); // pipes as array of strings
    char *command = *ptr;

    while (command != NULL)
    {
        if (i == 2)
            break;                        // hard code to ignore all commands after 2nd pipe
        char **args = parse_cmd(command); // this parses a space-separated command as arguments
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0 && i == 0) // 1st pipe, 1st child
        {
            close(pfd[0]);   // close pipe read end
            dup2(pfd[1], 1); // set pipe write end to stdout
            if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", args[0], strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        else if (pid == 0 && i == 1) // 2nd pipe, 2nd child
        {
            close(pfd[1]);   // close pipe write end
            dup2(pfd[0], 0); // set pipe read end to stdin
            if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "'%s': %s\n", args[0], strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            // exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else if (pid > 0) // parent
        {
            printf("Parent pid: %d and child's pid is %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)pid);
        }

        command = *++ptr;
        i++;
    }

    pid_t zombie_pid;
    int status;

    do
    {
        zombie_pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        printf("Child PID %d died with status %d\n", (int)zombie_pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    } while (zombie_pid > 0);
}
```

Comment: Using a debugger to debug forked processes is not easy, so I suggest you add a lot (and I really mean a ***lot***) of `printf` statements in your code to print out *everything* you do, and the values of exactly all variables when you use them.

Comment: It appears you are not closing all the file descriptors.  I would expect to see code that looks like `dup2(pfd[0], 0); close(pfd[0]); close(pfd[1])`, but it looks like all of your `dup2` calls are not followed by a closure of the dup'd fd.  But you don't show all your code, so this is just a guess based on a quick scan of incomplete code.

Comment: `printf("Error creating pipe\n"); exit(errno);` is invalid, since `printf` may modify `errno`.  If you want to return errno (which, really, you don't want to do), you would need to write `int save_errno = errno; fprintf(...); exit(save_errno)`. But the code you really want to write is `perror("pipe"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`.