# linux execvp ; ls cannot access |, No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec, systems-programming

I am trying to code a shell. But my shell doesn't execute the command - ls -l | less. I am using execvp. the code is given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int pid, status, num, len;
    char str[1000], cwd[100];
    char* word[100];

    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));

    while(1){
        chdir(cwd);

        printf("%s > ", cwd);

        gets(str);

        pid=vfork();

        if(pid == 0){
            num = 0;
            word[num] = strtok (str, " ");

            while (word[num] != NULL) {
                word[num] = strdup (word[num]);
                len = strlen (word[num]);
                if (strlen (word[num]) > 0)
                    if (word[num][len-1] == '\n')
                        word[num][len-1] = '\0';
                word[++num] = strtok (NULL, " ");
            }

            if(strcmp(word[0], "cd") == 0){
                chdir(word[1]);
                getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
            }
            else{
                execvp(word[0],word);
            }

            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            wait(&status);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `|` is a shell related token, as far as I know. Doing it outside of a shell doesn't really work because its the shell that reads `|` and makes the magic happen. Without the shell to make the magic piping happen... it doesn't work.

Comment: SO is there any other way I can run |? can I somehow the string and with brute force make it work

Comment: @Cornstalks speaks truly. `execvp` is written to execute one command with a set of parameters (if needed). You can try `system` to call a full-blown shell command line.

Comment: Before you use `vfork()`, read up on what you're allowed to do in a child process.  I don't think `chdir()` or `getpwd()` are allowed.  Use `fork()` instead.  It probably isn't your main problem (yet), but be very, very wary of the constraints on `vfork()`.

Comment: See, amongst many possibilities, [C program with pipes to execute `ps aux | grep firefox | tee processes.txt`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582446/c-program-with-pipes-to-excecute-ps-aux-grep-firefox-tee-processes-txt/).

Comment: Also, I just want to say that I wish I had said "it's" instead of "its," but alas can no longer edit my comment. Just in case anyone's eyes bleed from the typo.

Comment: Study the source code of existing free software shells like `sash` or `bash` and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ls -l | less` is actually a shell command line that consists of two processes connected by a pipe. The `execvp()` call can only spawn a single process.

If you want to do this from your program, you must invoke the shell explicitly - either by using the `system()` call, or by changing the command line to `sh -c 'ls -l | less'`. Your `word` array should look like this:

```
word[0] = "sh"
word[1] = "-c"
word[2] = "ls -l | less"
word[3] = NULL
```

[EDIT] Alternatively, you could do what the shell is doing internally: spawn two processes and connect them with a pipe. This would involve using the `fork()`, `pipe()`, `dup2()` and `execve()` calls. However, invoking the shell is much less work, and since `less` is an interactive program anyway, you don't need to worry about performance that much: anything that takes less than 100 ms is perceived as instantaneous.

Comment: +1 Just for the abuse of `sh` as the execvp command. Didn't see that coming =P.

Comment: @WhozCraig: GNU libc `system()` internally does exactly the same thing under the hood. See: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/system.c;hb=HEAD

Comment: @KrzysztofKosiński That's *awesome*. I had no idea. Thanks!

Comment: `popen()` might be helpful as well perhaps.

Comment: Coding a shell using the system shell (thru `system`, `popen` or execution of `/bin/sh`) is not exactly conforming to the goals of the homework.....