# Multipiping implementation with File descriptor limitation not working properly. (shell)

Tags: c

i'm actually working on the implementation of multipipes in a shell and i must say i'm having 
some problems resolving issues i've encountered in the project.

One particular detail makes this multipipe implementation quite hard, it must work with a very low limit on files descriptors.

For example if you enter the command "limit descriptors 10" on bash or tcsh you can still run a very long command like "ls|cat|cat|cat|cat|cat|cat|cat|cat|cat|cat|cat|cat|wc" without having any error messages or broken pipe.

My multipipe must do the same.

I've been working on this issue and came up with a a few different versions.
The last one seems to work partially but doesn't conform to the display of a real shell.
What i have  done is creat a tree that execute the line of command "cat|ls|wc".

In a real shell the "wc" should display it's result and then "cat" should be waiting to receive one user input before quitting.

In my version the "cat" loop appears first waiting for the users imput before having wc display it's results and quitting.

My "wc" displays the good results it just seems that it's execution is delayed. it's as though it's waiting to receive a signal from a pipe or something else...
I can't figure out why "wc" isn't displayed instantly
i'm maybe not closing  or duping a pipe correctly ?

You'll find my code following these lines.

Thanks in advance for any help or tips you can give me.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define PIPE    1
#define CMD 2
typedef struct  s_tree
{
  char      *cmd;
  int       fd[2];
  char      type;
  struct s_tree *left;
  struct s_tree *right;
  struct s_tree *parent;
}       t_tree;

/*
static void test_tree(t_tree *tree)
{
  if (tree == NULL)
    {
      printf("Null\n");
      return ;
    }
  if (tree->type == PIPE)
    printf("Type pipe\n");
  else if (tree->type == CMD)
    printf("Type cmd : %s\n", tree->cmd);
  if (tree->left != NULL)
    {
      printf("Gauche\n");
      test_tree(tree->left);
    }
  if (tree->right != NULL)
    {
      printf("Droite\n");
      test_tree(tree->right);
    }
}
*/

void    my_exit(int value)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "EXITING %d\n", value);
  perror(NULL);
  exit(value);
}

int execute_cmd(t_tree *tree)
{
  if (execlp(tree->cmd, tree->cmd, NULL) < 0)
    my_exit(11);
  return (0);
}

int execute_pipe(t_tree *tree)
{
  int   statusleft;
  int   statusright;
  pid_t pidright;
  pid_t pidleft;
  int   fd[2];

  if (pipe(fd) < 0)
    my_exit(1);
  if ((pidleft = fork()) < 0)
    my_exit(2);
  if (pidleft == 0)
    {
      if (close(fd[1]) < 0
      || close(0) < 0)
    my_exit(3);
      if (dup2(fd[0], 0) < 0)
    my_exit(4);
      if (tree->left->type == PIPE)
    return (execute_pipe(tree->left));
      else if (tree->left->type == CMD)
    return (execute_cmd(tree->left));
    }
  else
    {
      if (close(fd[0]) < 0
      || close(1) < 0)
    my_exit(6);
      if ((pidright = fork()) < 0)
    my_exit(5);
      if (pidright == 0)
    {
      if (dup2(fd[1], 1) < 0)
        my_exit(7);
      if (tree->right->type == PIPE)
        return (execute_pipe(tree->right));
      else if (tree->right->type == CMD)
        return (execute_cmd(tree->right));
    }
      else
    {
      if (close(fd[1]) < 0
          || close(0) < 0)
        my_exit(8);
      if (waitpid(pidright, &statusright, 0) < 0)
        my_exit(9);
    }
      if (waitpid(pidleft, &statusleft, 0) < 0)
    my_exit(10);
    }
  return (0);
}

/*
**                  PIPE
**                  /\
**                 /  \
**                /    \
**              wc     PIPE
**                     /\
**                    /  \
**                   /    \
**                 ls     cat
**
** cat | ls | wc
*/

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
  t_tree    *tree;

  tree = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
  tree->left = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
  tree->right = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
  tree->right->left = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
  tree->right->right = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
  tree->type = PIPE;
  tree->left->right = NULL;
  tree->left->left = NULL;
  tree->left->type = CMD;
  tree->left->cmd = malloc(strlen("/usr/bin/wc") + 1);
  strcpy(tree->left->cmd, "/usr/bin/wc");
  tree->right->type = PIPE;
  tree->right->left->right = NULL;
  tree->right->left->left = NULL;
  tree->right->left->type = CMD;
  tree->right->left->cmd = malloc(strlen("/bin/ls") + 1);
  strcpy(tree->right->left->cmd, "/bin/ls");
  tree->right->right->left = NULL;
  tree->right->right->left = NULL;
  tree->right->right->type = CMD;
  tree->right->right->cmd = malloc(strlen("/bin/cat") + 1);
  strcpy(tree->right->right->cmd, "/bin/cat");
  tree->parent = NULL;
  tree->left->parent = tree;
  tree->right->parent = tree;
  tree->right->left->parent = tree->right;
  tree->right->right->parent = tree->right;
  /*test_tree(tree);*/
  return (execute_pipe(tree));
}
```

Comment: At any given point while you're creating the pipeline 'cat | ls | wc', you need at most two pipes (4 descriptors) plus the standard 3 (0, 1, 2) — unless you're planning to have all the processes in the pipeline be children of the parent shell (which `bash` may do).

Comment: I'm sure you're not closing enough file descriptors.  I'm not sure whether I'm willing to spend the time working out where you need to close more, but after you `dup2()` a descriptor to standard input or standard output, you should close the original descriptor.  The tree structure is interesting, but a simple array would be sufficient.  You never use the `fd` member of the tree structure (nor do you use the parent member of it).

Comment: Try taking a look at SO 13636252: [C Minishell adding pipelines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13636252).  That shows how to create a multi-part pipeline — 5 parts in the example answer I give.  No tree structure.

Comment: Thx for you comments.I use a recursive function enableling me to recycle the descriptors, making the pipeline quite tricky. In the link you gave me the descriptors don't seem to be reclycle and that is a problem for me. I aggree with you on the fact i must be missing something with my descriptors but i don't seem to be able to put the finger on it if you find a clue it would be great.

Comment: One curiosity is that you end up with 5 processes.  You have the parent shell, then you get a process for `wc`, then there's a shell which sits around coordinating, and finally processes for `ls` and `cat`.  So, in one run, I had PIDs 80710, 80711 (`wc`), 80712, 80713 (`ls`) and 80714 (`cat`).  The `cat` can't terminate until it has read some input and attempts to write to the pipe, which sends it a SIGPIPE signal, or you give it EOF in which case it writes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an instrumented version of your code, and the output from it.

#### Output

```
$ nsh
4625: Main shell
4625: Node type 1
4625: Left: 0x7FBFE8403980, Right: 0x7FBFE84039A0
4625: Pipe: r 3, w 4
Parent 4625 - waiting for R-Child (4627)
4625: ooo-o-----
4626: L-Child
4627: R-Child
4626: ooooo-----
4627: ooo-o-----
4627: Node type 1
4627: Left: 0x7FBFE84039C0, Right: 0x7FBFE84039E0
4626: Node type 2
4626: Command: /usr/bin/wc
4627: Pipe: r 3, w 4
4626: Left: 0x000000000000, Right: 0x000000000000
4626: Command: /usr/bin/wc
4626: ooo-------
Parent 4627 - waiting for R-Child (4629)
4627: ooo-o-----
4629: R-Child
4628: L-Child
4629: ooo-o-----
4629: Node type 2
4629: Command: /bin/cat
4628: ooooo-----
4629: Left: 0x000000000000, Right: 0x000000000000
4629: Command: /bin/cat
4629: ooo-------
4628: Node type 2
4628: Command: /bin/ls
4628: Left: 0x000000000000, Right: 0x000000000000
4628: Command: /bin/ls
4628: ooo-------

Parent 4627 - R-Child died 4629 = 0x000D
Parent 4627 - waiting for L-Child (4628)
4627: ooo-------
Parent 4627 - L-Child died 4628 = 0x0000
      49      49     595
Parent 4625 - R-Child died 4627 = 0x0000
Parent 4625 - waiting for L-Child (4626)
4625: ooo-------
Parent 4625 - L-Child died 4626 = 0x0000
$
```

#### Interpretation

The blank line is where I hit return, providing some input to the `cat` command.  As you can see if you follow carefully, `cat` has PID 4629; when it exits, it has status 0x000D, which indicates that it died from a SIGPIPE signal (13).

In this example run, the original shell is PID 4625. It creates a pipe with file descriptors 3 and 4, and then creates 4626 as the left child and 4627 as the right child.  PID 4627 creates a pipe (also on file descriptors 3 and 4; the others have been closed and/or redirected to standard input) and runs 4628 and 4629, which `ls` and `cat` (4626 becomes `wc`).  You have the parent process waiting for 4627 to exit; you have 4627 waiting for 4629 (`cat`); so nothing much happens until you type at `cat`.

When you do type at `cat`, it exits because the pipe is closed; 4629 is collected by 4627, which then goes on to collect 4628 (`ls`) too.  Now 4625 gets to collect 4627, and then 4626, and then itself terminates.

The tree is a little odd because it is set up with the leftmost process in the pipeline (`cat`) as the rightmost process in the tree.

Normally, the status of a pipeline is the status of the last process in the pipeline.  With `bash`, you can also get the exit statuses of the other processes in the pipeline, so the main shell has to launch all the processes in the pipeline (so that the processes are its children and it can wait for them and collect the exit statuses).

Whether it is what you actually want or not, the code seems to be behaving according to the implemented design.

More normally, rather than waiting for a specific process to die, you'd wait for any child to die, and then clean up your data structures accordingly.  But the pipeline doesn't finish before the `cat` does because you have a process waiting specifically for `cat`.

I'm not sure how you want to fix this.  As noted in the comments, I'd be inclined to structure it more like the code in [C Minishell Adding Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13636252).  However, that code is behaving oddly for me when the first process in the pipeline is reading from the terminal (e.g. for `cat | ls | wc`), giving me an I/O error.  And I've not managed to debug why!  I do know that if I pipe the input into that, or if I redirect it using `<<<`, it works fine.  I don't understand the error I am getting (which is irksome, to say the least).

#### Instrumentation

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PIPE    1
#define CMD     2

typedef struct s_tree
{
    char          *cmd;
    char           type;
    struct s_tree *left;
    struct s_tree *right;
}               t_tree;

enum { DESCRIPTORS_PER_LINE = 64 };

static void open_fds(int max_fd)
{
    int fd;
    struct stat buff;

    fprintf(stderr, "%d: ", (int)getpid());
    for (fd = 0; fd < max_fd; fd++)
    {
        if (fstat(fd, &buff) < 0)
            putc('-', stderr);
        else
            putc('o', stderr);
        if (fd % DESCRIPTORS_PER_LINE == DESCRIPTORS_PER_LINE - 1)
            putc('\n', stderr);
    }
    if (fd % DESCRIPTORS_PER_LINE != 0)
        putc('\n', stderr);
}

static void my_exit(int value)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "EXITING %d\n", value);
    perror(NULL);
    exit(value);
}

static void dump_node(t_tree *tree)
{
    assert(tree != 0);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Node type %d\n", (int)getpid(), tree->type);
    if (tree->cmd != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: Command: %s\n", (int)getpid(), tree->cmd);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Left: 0x%.12" PRIXPTR ", Right: 0x%.12" PRIXPTR "\n",
            (int)getpid(), (uintptr_t)tree->left, (uintptr_t)tree->right);
}

static int execute_cmd(t_tree *tree)
{
    //usleep((10 + rand() % 100) * 1000);
    assert(tree->type == CMD);
    dump_node(tree);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Command: %s\n", (int)getpid(), tree->cmd);
    open_fds(10);
    execlp(tree->cmd, tree->cmd, NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Exec fail (%s)\n", (int)getpid(), tree->cmd);
    my_exit(102);
    return(-1);
}

static int execute_tree(t_tree *tree)
{
    int statusleft;
    int statusright;
    pid_t pidright;
    pid_t pidleft;
    int fd[2];

    assert(tree->type == PIPE);
    dump_node(tree);
    if (pipe(fd) < 0)
        my_exit(1);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Pipe: r %d, w %d\n", (int)getpid(), fd[0], fd[1]);
    if ((pidleft = fork()) < 0)
        my_exit(2);
    if (pidleft == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: L-Child\n", (int)getpid());
        open_fds(10);
        fflush(0);
        if (close(fd[1]) < 0)
            my_exit(3);
        if (dup2(fd[0], 0) < 0)
            my_exit(4);
        close(fd[0]);
        if (tree->left->type == PIPE)
            return(execute_tree(tree->left));
        else if (tree->left->type == CMD)
            return(execute_cmd(tree->left));
        else
            my_exit(100);
    }
    else
    {
        if (tree->right != NULL)
        {
            if ((pidright = fork()) < 0)
                my_exit(5);
            if (close(fd[0]) < 0)
                my_exit(6);
            if (pidright == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: R-Child\n", (int)getpid());
                open_fds(10);
                if (dup2(fd[1], 1) < 0)
                    my_exit(7);
                close(fd[1]);
                if (tree->right->type == PIPE)
                    return(execute_tree(tree->right));
                else if (tree->right->type == CMD)
                    return(execute_cmd(tree->right));
                else
                    my_exit(101);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Parent %d - waiting for R-Child (%d)\n", (int)getpid(), pidright);
                open_fds(10);
                if (close(fd[1]) < 0)
                    my_exit(8);
                if (waitpid(pidright, &statusright, 0) < 0)
                    my_exit(9);
                fprintf(stderr, "Parent %d - R-Child died %d = 0x%.4X\n",
                       (int)getpid(), pidright, statusright);
            }
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent %d - waiting for L-Child (%d)\n", (int)getpid(), pidleft);
        open_fds(10);
        if (waitpid(pidleft, &statusleft, 0) < 0)
            my_exit(10);
        fprintf(stderr, "Parent %d - L-Child died %d = 0x%.4X\n",
               (int)getpid(), pidleft, statusleft);
    }
    return(0);
}

/*
** Pipes at RHS to avoid issues with slaash, backslash, newline, start
** being a comment start symbol
**
**                  PIPE         |
**                  /\           |
**                 /  \          |
**                /    \         |
**              wc     PIPE      |
**                     /\        |
**                    /  \       |
**                   /    \      |
**                 ls     cat    |
**
** cat | ls | wc
*/
int main(void)
{
    t_tree        *tree;

    setvbuf(stderr, 0, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ);

    printf("%d: Main shell\n", (int)getpid());
    tree = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    tree->left = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    tree->right = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    tree->right->left = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    tree->right->right = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    tree->type = PIPE;
    tree->left->right = NULL;
    tree->left->left = NULL;
    tree->left->type = CMD;
    tree->left->cmd = malloc(strlen("/usr/bin/wc") + 1);
    strcpy(tree->left->cmd, "/usr/bin/wc");
    tree->right->type = PIPE;
    tree->right->left->right = NULL;
    tree->right->left->left = NULL;
    tree->right->left->type = CMD;
    tree->right->left->cmd = malloc(strlen("/bin/ls") + 1);
    strcpy(tree->right->left->cmd, "/bin/ls");
    tree->right->right->left = NULL;
    tree->right->right->left = NULL;
    tree->right->right->type = CMD;
    tree->right->right->cmd = malloc(strlen("/bin/cat") + 1);
    strcpy(tree->right->right->cmd, "/bin/cat");
    //tree->parent = NULL;
    //tree->left->parent = tree;
    //tree->right->parent = tree;
    //tree->right->left->parent = tree->right;
    //tree->right->right->parent = tree->right;
    return(execute_tree(tree));
}
```