# Recursive Piping in Unix environment

Tags: c, unix, piping

I am trying to implement piping in Unix, and have been asked to do it recursively. I have a sh program that parses input by the pipe character and then forks a child process to begin the piping. I am going to use the command `cat file | grep the | more` as an example.

My sh.c program first parses the input string into pipeCmds which is just an array of char * that point at the different parts of the input string. It forks the first child and then begins the recursivePipe() call which should set up all the pipes. After the pipes are set up I exec("more") in this case.

```
 pid = fork();
 if(pid == 0){
     recursivePipe(pipeCmds[numCmds-2], numCmds-1);
     exec(pipeCmds[numCmds-1]); // exec("more")

 }else{
    pid = wait(getpid());
 }
```

Here is the recursivePipe function that should set up each pipe based on how many commands were in the string (ie. numCmds)

```
int recursivePipe(char * cmd, int index){

        /* cmd = more */
        int pid, fd, copy;
        int ttyfd;
        char tty[64];


        if(index < 1){
                printf("index is 0... RETURN\n");
                return;
        }
        pipe(pd);

        // First fork a new child to stage the WRITING proc
        printf("forking to %s from %s\n", cmd, pipeCmds[index]);
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
                // Child
                close(pd[0]); // Close the child's read

                //if(index != (numCmds-2)){ // If we are not on the last command, make stdout be the pipe
                        dup2(pd[1], 1);        // Place the WRITE end of the pipe into stdout so anything coming from the pipe
                        close(pd[1]);
                //}
                copy = dup(1);
                close(1);
                gettty(tty);
                ttyfd = open(tty, O_WRONLY);
                if(ttyfd == 1){

                printf("exec(%s) from %s\n", cmd, pipeCmds[index]);
                close(1);
                dup(copy);
                close(copy);
        }

                /*copy = dup(0);
                close(0);
                gettty(tty);

                ttyfd = open(tty, O_RDONLY);
                if(ttyfd == 0){
                getc();
                close(0);
                dup(copy);
                close(copy);
                }*/

                exec(cmd);
        }else{
                // Parent
                printf("in parent: %s[%d]\n", pipeCmds[index], index);
                close(pd[1]); // Close the parent's write since more doesn't have to write

                //if(index != 0){ // If we are not on the first command, make stdin be the pipe

                        dup2(pd[0], 0); // Place the READ end of pipe into stdin so that more's stdin comes from the pipe        
                        close(pd[0]);

                //}

                printf("lets recurse!:  %s[%d]\n", pipeCmds[index], index);
        //        if(index > 0){
                recursivePipe(pipeCmds[index-2], index-1); // This will set up all other procs too with correct pipes
                //pid = wait(getpid());
                // }

                printf("done recurse!: %s[%d]\n", pipeCmds[index], index);

        }

}
```

Basically, I attempt to pipe(), then in the child process I close the READ end of the pipe and set stdout to now be the pipe. So in this case, on the first call of recursivePipe(), the parent section is the "more" proc and the child section is the "grep the" part. So "more" closes its stdin and replaces it with the pipe so it reads all output from "grep the"

Based on my printf() inside the function, here is the output of that command:

```
forking to grep the from more
in parent: more[2]
lets recurse!: more[2]
forking to cat file from grep the
exec( grep the ) from more
exec(cat file) from grep the
in parent: grep the [1]
lets recurse!: grep the[1]
index is 0... RETURN
done recurse!: grep the [1]
done recurse!: more[2]
```

And then it appears to cat file correctly and send it to more, but the grep program is never used between the two. It is as if cat and more are communicating directly rather than through grep.

Can anyone with knowledge of the unix system help me figure out why my recursion isn't setting up the pipes correctly? Thanks

Comment: Off the bat, this is wrong `else{pid = wait(getpid());`.  This will have the parent waiting on itself.  You want the pid returned from the `fork`.  In `recursivePipe` you have `fd` defined as an int rather than an array of two ints even though you index it later.  Not sure how that even compiles.  Probably not your problem but things to clean up anyway. *Always check system call return values*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Minishell Adding Pipelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636252/c-minishell-adding-pipelines)

Comment: what do you mean fd is used as an array? fd is just a file descriptor.. Do you mean pd? pd are the 2 fds for the pipe

Comment: Sorry, pd then.  I didn't read the code very carefully.

Comment: [`recursive-piping.c`](https://gist.github.com/zed/7835043) provides similar to [@JonathanLeffler's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13640308/4279). It might help you to understand how `pipe()` can be used to solve the problem.

Comment: undefined reference to \`gettty'
undefined reference to \`exec'