# forks and pipes implementation linux compiler

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

I have the following code taken from the [“Pipes” section](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/pipes.html) of [Beej’s Guide to Unix IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/index.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pfds[2];

    pipe(pfds);

    if (!fork()) {
        close(1);       /* close normal stdout */
        dup(pfds[1]);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
        close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);
    } else {
        close(0);       /* close normal stdin */
        dup(pfds[0]);   /* make stdin same as pfds[0] */
        close(pfds[1]); /* we don't need this */
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code allows the user to see how many files are in a specific directory. How can I edit this code to implement the longer pipeline `cat /etc/passwd | cut –f1 –d: | sort`? Does anyone have any idea how to do this because I am completely stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Minishell Adding Pipelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636252/c-minishell-adding-pipelines)

Answer (score 0):

Feels like homework, so I'll just give you some pointers:

- The longer pipeline has two pipes, so you'll need to call pipe() twice. (I'd also check pipe's return value whilst I was at it.)
- There are three processes, which means two forks. Again, check fork()'s return value properly: it's tri-state: parent, child or failure, and your program should test all three cases.
- If you call pipe() twice up front, think carefully about which file descriptors (i.e. which ends of pipes) are which in each process, and hence which ones to close before invoking execlp(). I'd draw a picture.
- I'd prefer dup2() to dup(), since you're explicitly setting the target file descriptor, and so it makes sense to specify it in the call. Also avoids silly bugs.
- dup and execlp can fail, so I'd check their return values too...

Answer (score 0):

You need (depending on the length of the command list) some pipes. But: at maximum you need not more than two pipe-pair-fds for a process in the middle, for the first and the last you need one pipe-pair-fds. Be really sure to close the pipe-fds which are not needed - if not, the child processes might not get an EOF and never finish.

And (as user3392484 stated): check all system calls for error conditions and report them to the caller.  This will make life much easier.

I implemented something like this during the last days, maybe you want to have a look there: [pipexec.c](https://github.com/flonatel/pipexec/blob/master/pipexec.c#L303).

Kind regards - Andreas