# C piping using the command line arguments

Tags: c, input, fork, output, piping

I need some help emulating the "|" command in unix. I need to be able to use the output from the first argument as the input of the second, something as simple as ls and more. I got this code so far but I'm just stuck at this point. Any and all help would be helpful.-Thanks.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** words)
{ 
  char** args;
  char *cmd1[2] = { words[1], 0 };
  char *cmd2[2] = { words[2], 0 };
  int colon, arg1 ,i, pid, status;
  int thepipe[2];
  char ch;
  args = (char **) malloc(argc*(sizeof(char*)));
  colon = -1;
  for (i=0;(i<argc); i=i+1){
    if (strcmp(words[i],":") == 0) {
      colon = i;
    }
    else {}
  }
  pipe(thepipe);
  arg1 = colon;
  arg1 = arg1 - 1;
  for (i=0;(i<arg1); i=i+1){
    args[i] = (char*) (malloc(strlen(words[i+1])+1));
    strcpy(args[i], words[i+1]);
  }
  args[argc] = NULL;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    wait(&pid);
    dup2(thepipe[1], 1);
    close(thepipe[0]);
    printf("in new\n");
    execvp(*args, cmd1); 
  }
  else {
    close(thepipe[1]);
    printf("in old\n");
    while ((status=read(thepipe[0],&ch,1)) > 0){
    execvp(*args, cmd2);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. This isn't a program-level utility, it's the bash itself that does this.

Comment: I understand but I need to replicate that without using "|".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Have you looked for related questions. [SO 13636252 C Minishell Adding Pipelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636252/c-minishell-adding-pipelines) might be of relevance; so might a few hundred others.  You should lose the `else {}` line.

Comment: `man dup2`  You need to associate stdin/stdout with the appropriate ends of the pipe.

Comment: @ciphermagi - this is a standard 1st year assignment.

Comment: @Hogan I would expect Conway's Game of Life or building a hash table in the first year. I wouldn't expect something like this. This is busy-work.

Comment: @ciphermagi - It is all busy work when you know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `argv[1]` is a single word command (like `ls`) and `argv[2]` is a second single word command (like `more`), then:

#### Parent

1. Create a pipe.
2. Fork first child.
3. Fork second child.
4. Close both ends of the pipe.
5. Parent waits for both children to die, reports their exit status, and exits itself.

#### Child 1

1. Duplicates write end of pipe to standard output.
2. Close both ends of the pipe.
3. Uses `execvp()` to run the command in `argv[1]`.
4. Exits, probably with an error message written to standard error (if the `execvp()` returns).

#### Child 2

1. Duplicates read end of pipe to standard input.
2. Close both ends of the pipe.
3. Uses `execvp()` to run the command in `argv[2]`.
4. Exits, probably with an error message written to standard error (if the `execvp()` returns).

The only remaining trick is that you need to create a vector such as:

```
char cmd1[2] = { argv[1], 0 };
char cmd2[2] = { argv[2], 0 };
```

to pass as the second argument to `execvp()`.

---

Note that this outline does not break the strings up.  If you want to handle an invocation such as:

```
./execute "ls -la" "wc -wl"
```

then you will need to split each argument into separate words and create bigger arrays for `cmd1` and `cmd2`.  If you want to handle more than two commands, you need to think quite carefully about how you're going to manage the extra stages in the pipeline.  The first and last commands are different from those in the middle (so 3 processes has three different mechanisms, but 4 or more substantially uses the same mechanism over and over for all except the first and last commands).

Comment: So I need to make another child process in order to get it to work?

Comment: It depends; you can make it work with just one child.  The instructions get a bit shuffled around (you don't have the parent waiting for the children), so the only parental steps are 'create pipe' and fork first child.  The first child instructions are unchanged; the parent process then executes the second child instructions.