# Message queue between two forked processes causing invalid argument from msgsnd

Tags: c, fork, posix, message-queue

The program creates two child processes.  The first child process (1) reads text from stdin, removes any special chars, and spilts into words.  That part of the program works just fine.  Then while child (1) is splitting up the words it is sending each whole word through a message queue.  This part causes the invalid argument error.  Child 2 should then just print the message it got back to the screen.

At least that's how I planned on this working.  I'm kinda stuck and not really sure how to debug the message queue.  Right now it's throwing an error from

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <ctype.h>

# define QUEUE_PERMS 0644

static int message_queue = (int) 0;
static key_t key = (key_t) 0;

typedef struct message
{
  long mtype;
  char msg[100];
} mess_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  const char delimiters[] = " ,.-!?()1234567890@#$%^&*\n";
  char *word = NULL;
  size_t buffer = 100;
  char *token;
  mess_t message;
  mess_t message2;
  int i;


  // set up a message queue
   key = ftok(__FILE__,'x');

  // create queue
   message_queue = msgget(key, QUEUE_PERMS | IPC_CREAT);
   if(message_queue == -1){
    perror("creating message queue");
   }

  // create parcer process. This tokenizes the strings
  // and send each work to the sort function(s)
  switch(fork()){
    case 0:
      // child process # 1 starts here
      key = ftok(__FILE__,'x');
      message_queue = msgget(key, QUEUE_PERMS);

      // splitting the words up here, this works fine 
      while(getline(&word, &buffer, stdin) != EOF){
        token = strtok(word, delimiters);
        while(token != NULL){
          for(i = 0; token[i]; i++){
            token[i] = tolower(token[i]);
          }
          // set type to 1 to send
          message.mtype = 1;
          // copy the word (token) over to the message struct
          strcpy(message.msg,token);

          // **** I get a send failed: Invalid argument here  *****
          if(msgsnd(key, &message, sizeof(message), MSG_NOERROR) == -1){
            perror("send failed");
          }
          token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        }
      }    
      break;

    case -1:
      perror("error fork\n");
      break;

    default:
      wait(NULL);
      break;
  }

  // this process should read the message an print it out
  switch(fork()){
    case 0:
    // child process # 2 starts here
      key = ftok(__FILE__,'x');
      message_queue = msgget(key, QUEUE_PERMS ); 
      msgrcv(key, &message2, sizeof(message),1, MSG_NOERROR); 
      printf("child process got %s\n", message2.msg);
      break;

    case -1:
      perror("error fork\n");
      break;

    default:
      wait(NULL);
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One recommendation: use functions to encapsulate the sender and the receiver actions.  You can then simplify your `main()` function so that it simply invokes these functions at the correct point.  Your code is pretty good; it passes my compilation test (`gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration -Werror  mq.c -o mq`) with minimal changes (`int main(void)` since neither `argc` nor `argv` is used; and `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` before any headers are included).  That's high praise; few programs get as close.

Comment: Yep I compile with pretty much every flag I can think of.  Harder to make dumb errors that way.

Comment: That's very good; it makes it easier (and more interesting) to debug the problem for you.  You might want to think about connecting to the message queue (`msgget()`) before you fork; reduces repetition.  You'll need to worry about `perror()` returning if it is called to report an error.  I recommend a function (surprise, surprise) to do error reporting and exiting.  It can be simple (single string argument, as with `perror()`) or flexible (format string and variable arguments, as with `printf()`).  My production code is configurable to add the name of the program, time, PID, etc.

Comment: You can find a rudimentary but effective version of my `stderr.h` and `stderr.c` in [C Minishell -- adding pipelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636252/c-minishell-adding-pipelines/13640308#13640308)

Comment: great! thanks for the help.  I'll work on breaking stuff out into functions.  That's one habit I need to pick up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the `message_queue` message queue ID with `msgget()`, but you then try to send to `msgsnd()` using the `key` instead of the message queue ID.

You have the same problem with `msgrcv()` too.

When I fix those two, I can run the program:

```
$ ./mq
abelone apathy
child process got abelone
child process got apathy
$
```

I typed `abelone apathy` on one line, then <kbd>Control-D</kbd> to indicate EOF.

As you've got it organized, the writing process fills the message queue before the reading process is enabled.  As long as the input isn't too big, that works.  However, you probably really want the two processes running concurrently.  You'll need to move the `wait()` calls to give you the concurrency.  (Another advantage of properly separating code into functions — it is easier to spot such problems if you hide as much as possible.)

Comment: Thanks!  I see what you mean about splitting things up.  I'm getting weird results where only a few words are getting through from larger strings.  I'm still happy something is getting through though!

Answer (score 2):

(1) Wrong value to `msgsnd/msgrcv`.  Use thre return value of `msgget` which is `message_queue` in your code.

(2) Your `fork` code is wrong. The parent will create one child then hit `wait` and wait before the 1st child dies before continuing on to create the 2nd child.  You will want to reconsider using `exit` in some of places you are just using `break` in your switch statements.