# Multiple pipe implementation

Tags: c, fork

Im currently working on implementing pipes for my shell. My current pipe implementation works for single pipes (A | B), but not for more than one (A | B | C).

Example: "ls | grep 'p' | wc"
In this situation, the 2nd output does not redirect its output to the wc command. Any tips?

```
                int fd[2];
                pipe(fd);                    
                int fd_past = 0;

                //commands are in A1 -> process -> Tokens
                while(A1->process != NULL) {
                    child = fork();
                    if (child == 0) {
                        dup2(fd_past,0);
                        close(fd[0]);                            
                        dup2(fd[1], 1);
                        Execute(A1->process->tokenCount, A1->process->Tokens);

                    } else {                            
                        close(fd[1]);
                        //save input for next command
                        fd_past = fd[0];   
                    }
                    A1->process = A1->process->next;
                }
```

Comment: You can't keep using the same pipe, you need to create a new pipe for each child that you fork.

Comment: @Barmar, would moving the line pipe(fd) under the fork help?

Comment: No, you need to create the pipe before you fork, so that you can connect one end to the parent's `stdout` and the other end to the child's `stdin`.

Comment: It needs to be inside the `while`, but before `fork`.

Comment: @Barmar. Hmm, for some odd reason that breaks the basic one pipe implementation too.

Comment: You need to treat the first and last processes specially. The first process doesn't have a pipe connected to its input, and the last process doesn't have a pipe connected to its output.

Comment: Someone asks a question like this almost every day, if you do a little searching you should be able to find previous answers.

Comment: One example of a question about this problem is [C minishell — adding pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636252/).  There are many others.

Comment: @Barmar, your advice about implementing a check if it is the last or first command helped me solve it. Thank you!