# c Pipes causing program to hang in some cases

Tags: c, unix, pipe, pipeline

I'm trying to use pipes to link the stdout of 1 command exec'd to the stdin of another. Eg mimic (cmd1 | cmd2)

Below is a heavily stripped down version of my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argC, char *argv[])
{

    //Run first command
    int fds[2];
    if (pipe (fds) < 0) {       //Create pipe
        fprintf (stderr, "Pipe Failed\n");
    }

    int pid;
    if ((pid = fork ()) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Fork 1 Failed\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {             //First child proccess
        close (fds[0]);         //Close input end of pipe
        dup2 (fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);   //Set stdout to output pipe
        close (fds[1]);         //Close output end of pipe

        fprintf (stderr, "Exec 1 executing now\n");
        execlp ("./addone", "./addone", NULL);  //execute first command - Doesnt cause hang
        //execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);//Causes hang
        fprintf (stderr, "Exec 1 failed\n");
    } else {                    //First parent segment
        int returnStatus;
        waitpid (pid, &returnStatus, 0);        //Wait for child 1 to finish

        fprintf (stderr, "Back to parent 1\n");
    }

    //Run second command
    if ((pid = fork ()) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Fork 2 failed\n");
    }

    if (pid == 0) {             //second child proccess
        dup2 (fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);    //Set stdin to input pipe
        close (fds[0]);         //Close input end of pipe
        close (fds[1]);         //Close output end of pipe

        fprintf (stderr, "Exec 2 executing now\n");
        execlp ("./addone", "./addone", NULL);  //execute first command - Doesnt cause hang
        //execlp("wc", "wc", NULL);//Causes hang
        fprintf (stderr, "Exec 2 failed\n");
    } else {                    //second parent segment
        int returnStatus;
        waitpid (pid, &returnStatus, 0);        //Wait for child 2 to finish

        fprintf (stderr, "Back to parent 2\n");
        //Done with pipes
        close (fds[0]);
        close (fds[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the program I attempt to make a pipe and route the first execs stdout to the seconds stdin. When attempting to run the program using ls | wc as my execs my program hangs on the 2nd exec. However when I use a simple program "./addone" as my execs the entire execution finishes properly.

Where "addone" is a small program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int value = 0;
    scanf("%d", &value);
    value++;
    printf("%d\n", value);
}
```

Its been suggested that my problem may be with there being an input pipe being left open but I cant work out where that would happen, and it doesn't explain why my program runs perfectly when using my simple test program.

Any advice as to what would be causing this hang would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to close the pipe ends in the parent process. Because `pipe` was called before `fork` so it is opened in both the parent and the child process. It's not a problem for your simple program because it does not loop waiting for `EOF` like `wc` would. The `EOF` never comes if the pipe is still being held open by any process.

Comment: Dont I already do that with close(fds[0]); close(fds[1]);
Or should I move those to before the wait statement in the parent?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't strip something important out of your program? In the example you posted I would expect it to hang at the first waitpid as long as the program being exec'ed writes anything to stdout - the printf in the child would block because nothing is reading from the other end of the pipe,  while the parent would in turn block waiting for the child. Suggestions: 1) close unused pipe ends in both the parent and the child immediately  (ie close fds[1] in parent after 1st fork etc. 2) don't wait for 1st child before starting the second, wait for both at the end instead

Comment: @Killedan9 Yes, you have to do it before the `waitpitd`. Otherwise the child process does not exit and he `waitpid` never unblocks.

Comment: @davlet "the printf in the child would block because nothing is reading from the other end of the pipe". I don't think that is correct. Perhaps you are thinking of a [fifo](http://linux.die.net/man/4/fifo). A pipe does not have that behaviour. And anyway, as already pointed out, the parent process has both ends open.

Comment: @kaylum I could swear pipes behave the same... but anyway, even if you are right, the pipe's buffer is only a few kilobytes, so if the child prints enough characters, it will block eventually, while the parent is stuck in waitpid... so you still can't wait until after forking both of them

Comment: @davlet Yes, I agree that the `waitpid` calls should be after all the `fork` calls.

Comment: You will also need a pipe for each end of the stream. (a minimum of 2) Both should be opened with `pipe` prior to calling `fork`. For the first part of the pipeline you will `dup2` the *write-end* of the first file-descriptor (closing all others in the child process), and then for the second command in your pipeline in the child process, `dup2` the read-end of the 1st descriptor and the write-end of the 2nd (close all others), finally after the child finishes `dup2` the read-end of the 2nd descriptor and read from `stdin`.

Comment: You can look at an automation of this process in [**C Minishell Adding Pipelines**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636252/c-minishell-adding-pipelines).

Comment: the `exec()` family of functions (if the `exec()` does not fail) does not return,  So if it returnes, then always/only code: `perror( "exec failed" ); exit(1);  To create/run a third process, another call to `fork()` is needed in the parent process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you got your problem solved or not, but continuing from the comments, if you are going to build a pipeline, the key is understanding that if you write to a pipe in one process, you must read from that same pipe in the next process, and write to a 2nd pipe if you are to continue the pipeline. Now you can automate the process as shown in the link [**C Minishell Adding Pipelines**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636252/c-minishell-adding-pipelines), but for learning purposes, it is probably easier to understand if you just work through your single linear example.

Below is the implementation of your code using two file descriptors `fd1` and `fd2`. Your `addone` process will first read from plain old `stdin`, so there is no manipulating of file descriptors for its read. However, for its write, it must use the *write-end* (for lack of better words) of `fd1` to pipe its output to the next child process.

The next child process must read from the *input-end* of that same `fd1` to receive its input and it must write to the *output-end* of another file descriptor `fd2`. After both childs have exited, then the parent process must read from where?? (What was the last pipe written too...? Ahah!) `fd2`. So the parent dups the *read-end* of `fd2` (closing all other unused ends) and read the final answer of how many `addone` added to the initial number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (void) {

    int fd1[2], fd2[2];  /* file descriptors 1 & 2 */
    int pid;

    if (pipe (fd1) < 0 || pipe (fd2) < 0) { /* open both pipes */
        fprintf (stderr, "pipe creation failed\n");
    }

    if ((pid = fork ()) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "fork 1 failed\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {                     /* first child */
        dup2 (fd1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);   /* dup write-end of 1st */
        close (fd1[0]);                 /* close all others */
        close (fd2[0]);
        close (fd2[1]);

        fprintf (stderr, "Exec 1 executing now\n");
        execlp ("./addone", "./addone", NULL);
        fprintf (stderr, "Exec 1 failed\n");
    }
    else {
        int returnStatus;
        waitpid (pid, &returnStatus, 0);
        fprintf (stderr, "Back to parent 1\n");
    }

    if ((pid = fork ()) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Fork 2 failed\n");
    }

    if (pid == 0) {                     /* second child */
        dup2 (fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);    /* dup read-end of 1st  */
        dup2 (fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);   /* dup write-end of 2nd */
        close (fd1[1]);                 /* close all others */
        close (fd2[0]);

        fprintf (stderr, "Exec 2 executing now\n");
        execlp ("./addone", "./addone", NULL);
        fprintf (stderr, "Exec 2 failed\n");
    }
    else {
        int returnStatus;
        waitpid (pid, &returnStatus, 0);
        fprintf (stderr, "Back to parent 2\n");
    }

    dup2 (fd2[0], 0);   /* dup read-end of 2nd */
    close (fd2[1]);     /* close all others */
    close (fd1[0]);
    close (fd1[1]);

    int total;
    scanf ("%d", &total);
    printf ("The total was: %d\n\n", total);

    close (fd2[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo 10 | ./bin/pipeaddone
Exec 1 executing now
Back to parent 1
Exec 2 executing now
Back to parent 2
The total was: 12
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions. Once you get it, it makes sense. If you don't use it for a while, don't worry, you'll get to re-learn it all over again `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I've managed to get my program to work and I finally understand what pipes are doing.

Comment: Glad I could help. It had been about a year since I last wrote a piece of code using this approach, so -- I got to enjoy learning it all over again `:)`