# Implementing pipeline in C, when to wait to kill child processes?

Tags: c, unix, fork

I am attempting to implement a pipeline in C that will execute multiple commands at the same time (for example: ls -l | grep key | less). Below is a bare-bones version of the code I am using:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i;
   pid_t pid;

   for(i = 1; i < argc-1; i++)
   {
       int pd[2];
       pipe(pd);

       if ((pid = fork()) == 0) 
       {
           /* child */
           dup2(pd[1], 1);
           execlp(argv[i], argv[i], NULL);
       }

       dup2(pd[0], 0);
       close(pd[1]);
   }

   execlp(argv[i], argv[i], NULL);
}
```

It works, however it sometimes leaves zombie processes. I know I need to wait(&status), but am not sure how to identify when my read is EOF for that process and I can kill it. At what point in my code do I check for EOF, and how do I go about doing it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't "kill" the children, they "die" themselves. Just wait for them.

Comment: `when to wait to kill children`... you just got your own NSA satellite!

Comment: How exactly does this leave zombie processes?

Comment: A post about infanticide and zombies o.O

Comment: But if the parent processes completes before it's children, it will leave behind zombie processes. If I wait before my final call to execlp it will block, and if placed after it will do nothing.

Comment: @JDweyer No, if the parent process exits before its children, they will become orphans and get adopted by init (pid 1), which waits for them to die.

Comment: This might help you: http://buedt.tistory.com/34

Comment: Let's say I'm running this code with the input file being an extremely large text file. If I want to pipe the commands (uniq | head) the uniq will be left as a zombie process. I have verified this numerous times with the ps command.

Comment: Instead of using the master process to exec the last command, exec the last command in a child process, too.  After all the children have been started, wait for them all to finish via `wait()` or `waitpid()`.

Comment: In any case, @JDweyer, it is not an issue for a few zombie processes to hang around until their original parent or PID 1 gets around to cleaning them up.  That is a temporary state.  It only becomes an issue if a long-running process creates many children and fails to clean them up -- in that case, the process table can fill up, but it takes a lot of processes.

Comment: In the code shown, there's no call for any waiting; the last `execlp()` replaces the last process that might do any waiting with another. So, to even consider waiting, you'd need to repackage your code as a separate function, and your revised `main()` would fork, the child would execute the pipeline as shown, while the parent would wait for the child to die.  It could then loop and prompt for a new input.  As it stands, you can only execute single word commands, not commands with arguments.  You'd have to split up the multi-word arguments before calling `execvp()` instead of `execlp()`.

Comment: I attempted all of your advice but unfortunately no luck yet. And yes @JonathanLeffler the above code is just a very rough outline of what I'm doing, I am parsing for arguments and such and using execvp().

Comment: I'm going to point you at [C minishell — adding pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636252/c-minishell-adding-pipelines/13640308#13640308).  The code works, though I'm not 100% convinced that it is as simple as it could be.  Note that when working with pipes in shells, it is almost invariably a mistake if you do not close both the file descriptors returned by `pipe()` (after appropriate redirection).  Code at [GitHub](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-1363-6252).

Comment: Also note that you can implement a pipeline two ways: (1) parent process forks child which runs the last process in the pipeline, and the child forks other processes that run the other processes in the pipeline, and (2) the parent process forks each child in the pipeline, and can wait for all of them to complete, unlike under option 1.  The classic way is (1); Bash implements (2) because it wants to detect failure anywhere in the pipeline (`shopt -s pipefail`).  IIRC, the x-ref'd answer implements (1), but it is years since I wrote it.

Comment: I was eventually able to resolve the issue and get everything working properly, thanks for the help all!