# How to correctly close unused pipes?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, system-calls

I'm implementing a simplified shell which supports pipe.
A part of my code shown below runs fine, but I'm not sure why it works.

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include "include/command.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string rawCommand;
    IndividualCommand tempCommand = {};

    int pipeFD[2] = {PIPE_IN, PIPE_OUT};
    int firstPipeRead, firstPipeWrite, secondPipeRead, secondPipeWrite;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "% ";
        getline(cin, rawCommand);

        if (rawCommand == "exit")
            break;

        Command *command = new Command(rawCommand);
        deque<IndividualCommand> commandQueue = command->parse();

        delete command;

        while (!commandQueue.empty())
        {
            tempCommand = commandQueue.front();
            commandQueue.pop_front();

            firstPipeRead = secondPipeRead;
            firstPipeWrite = secondPipeWrite;

            if (tempCommand.outputStream == PIPE_OUT)
            {
                pipe(pipeFD);
                secondPipeRead = pipeFD[0];
                secondPipeWrite = pipeFD[1];
            }

            pid_t child_pid;
            child_pid = fork();

            int status;

            // child process
            if (child_pid == 0)
            {
                if (tempCommand.redirectToFile != "")
                {
                    int fd = open(tempCommand.redirectToFile.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
                    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
                    close(fd);
                }

                if (tempCommand.inputStream == PIPE_IN)
                {
                    close(firstPipeWrite);
                    dup2(firstPipeRead, STDIN_FILENO);
                    close(firstPipeRead);
                }
                if (tempCommand.outputStream == PIPE_OUT)
                {
                    close(secondPipeRead);
                    dup2(secondPipeWrite, STDOUT_FILENO);
                    close(secondPipeWrite);
                }

                if (tempCommand.argument != "")
                    execl(tempCommand.executable.c_str(), tempCommand.executable.c_str(), tempCommand.argument.c_str(), NULL);
                else
                    execl(tempCommand.executable.c_str(), tempCommand.executable.c_str(), NULL);
            }
            else
            {
                close(secondPipeWrite);
                if (commandQueue.empty())
                    waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

command.h

```cpp
#ifndef COMMAND_H
#define COMMAND_H

#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

#define PIPE_IN  0x100000
#define PIPE_OUT 0x100001

struct IndividualCommand
{
    string executable = "";
    string argument = "";
    string redirectToFile = "";
    int inputStream = STDIN_FILENO;
    int outputStream = STDOUT_FILENO;
    int errorStream = STDERR_FILENO;
};

class Command
{
private:
    string rawCommand, tempString;
    queue<string> splittedCommand;
    deque<IndividualCommand> commandQueue;
    stringstream commandStream;
    IndividualCommand tempCommand;
    bool isExecutableName;

public:
    Command(string rawCommand);
    deque<IndividualCommand> parse();
};

#endif
```

command.cpp

```cpp
#include "include/command.h"

Command::Command(string rawCommand)
{
    this->rawCommand = rawCommand;
    isExecutableName = true;
}

deque<IndividualCommand>  Command::parse()
{
    commandStream << rawCommand;

    while (!commandStream.eof())
    {
        commandStream >> tempString;
        splittedCommand.push(tempString);
    }

    while (!splittedCommand.empty())
    {
        tempString = splittedCommand.front();
        splittedCommand.pop();

        if (isExecutableName)
        {
            tempCommand.executable = tempString;
            isExecutableName = false;

            if (!commandQueue.empty() && commandQueue.back().outputStream == PIPE_OUT)
                tempCommand.inputStream = PIPE_IN;
        }
        else
        {
            // normal pipe
            if (tempString == "|")
            {
                tempCommand.outputStream = PIPE_OUT;
                isExecutableName = true;
                commandQueue.push_back(tempCommand);
                tempCommand = {};
            }
            // redirect to file
            else if (tempString == ">")
            {
                tempCommand.redirectToFile = splittedCommand.front();
                splittedCommand.pop();
            }
            // argv
            else
                tempCommand.argument = tempString;
        }

        if (splittedCommand.empty())
        {
            commandQueue.push_back(tempCommand);
            tempCommand = {};
        }
    }

    return commandQueue;
}
```

So basically the communication is established between two child processes, not between child and parent. (I'm using those first and second pipes to avoid overwriting FDs with consecutive calls to pipe() when facing something like "ls | cat |cat").

The shell originally got stuck because the write end was not closed, and thus the read end got blocked. I've tried closing everything in both the child processes, but nothing changed.

My question is why `close(secondPipeWrite);` in the parent process solved everything? Does it mean that it is the write end of the pipe that really matters, and we don't have to care about whether the read end is closed explicitly?

Moreover, why I don't need to close anything in the child process and it still works?

Comment: Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
We should not have to guess at what is not present.  We should be able to run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidents will happen! Things will sometimes seem to work when there is no good reason for them to do so reliably.  A multi-stage pipeline is not guaranteed to work if you do not close all the unused pipe descriptors properly, even though it happens to work for you.  You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child processes, in particular.  You should close all the unused ends of all the pipes.

Here's a 'Rule of Thumb' I've included in other answers.

---

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD` or `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC`.

---

If the parent process will not communicate with any of its children via
the pipe, it must ensure that it closes both ends of the pipe early
enough (before waiting, for example) so that its children can receive
EOF indications on read (or get SIGPIPE signals or write errors on
write), rather than blocking indefinitely.
Even if the parent uses the pipe without using `dup2()`, it should
normally close at least one end of the pipe — it is extremely rare for
a program to read and write on both ends of a single pipe.

Note that the `O_CLOEXEC` option to
[`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html),
and the `FD_CLOEXEC` and `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` options to `fcntl()` can also factor
into this discussion.

If you use
[`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html)
and its extensive family of support functions (21 functions in total),
you will need to review how to close file descriptors in the spawned process
([`posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose.html),
etc.).

Note that using `dup2(a, b)` is safer than using `close(b); dup(a);`
for a variety of reasons.
One is that if you want to force the file descriptor to a larger than
usual number, `dup2()` is the only sensible way to do that.
Another is that if `a` is the same as `b` (e.g. both `0`), then `dup2()`
handles it correctly (it doesn't close `b` before duplicating `a`)
whereas the separate `close()` and `dup()` fails horribly.
This is an unlikely, but not impossible, circumstance.

---

Note that if the wrong process keeps a pipe descriptor open, it can prevent processes from detecting EOF.  If the last process in a pipeline has the write end of a pipe open where a process (possibly itself) is reading until EOF on the read end of that pipe, the process will never get EOF.

#### Reviewing the C++ code

On the whole, your code was good.  My default compilation options picked two problems with `close(firstPipeWrite)` and `close(firstPipeRead)` operating on uninitialized variables; they were treated as errors because I compile with:

```
c++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -o main.o main.cpp
```

But that was all — which is remarkably good work.

However, those errors also point to where your problem is.

Let's suppose you have a command input which requires two pipes (P1 and P2) and three processes (or commands, C1, C2, C3), such as:

```
who | grep -v root | sort
```

You want the commands set up as follows:

- C1: `who` — creates P1; standard input = stdin, standard output = P1[W]
- C2: `grep` — creates P2; standard input = P1[R], standard output = P2[W]
- C3: `sort` — creates no pipe; standard input = P2[R], standard output = stdout

The PN[R] notation means the read descriptor of pipe N, etc.

A more elaborate pipeline, such as `who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`, with 5 commands and 4 pipes is similar: it simply has more processes CN (with N = 2, 3, 4) which create PN and run with standard input coming from P(N-1)[R] and standard output going to PN[W].

A two-command pipeline has just one pipe, of course, and the structure:

- C1 — creates P1; standard input = stdin, standard output = P1[W]
- C2 — creates no pipe; standard input = P1[R], standard output = stdout

And a one-command (degenerate) pipeline has zero pipes, of course, and the structure:

- C1 — creates no pipe; standard input = stdin, standard output = stdout

Note that you need to know whether the command you're processing is first, last, or in the middle of the pipeline — the plumbing work to be done for each is different.  Also, if you have a multi-command pipeline (three or more commands), you can close the older pipes after a while; they won't be needed again. So as you're processing C3, both ends of P1 can be closed permanently; they won't be referenced again. You need the input pipe and the output pipe for the current process; any older pipes can be closed by the process coordinating the plumbing.

You need to decide which process is coordinating the plumbing.  The easiest way in some respects is to have the original (parent) shell process launch all the sub-processes, left-to-right — which is what you're doing — but it is by no means the only way.

With the shell process launching the child processes, it is crucial that the shell eventually close all the descriptors of all the pipes it opened, so that the child processes can detect EOF.  This must be done before waiting for any of the children.  Indeed, all the processes in the pipeline must be launched before the parent can afford to wait for any of them — those processes must run concurrently, in general, as otherwise, the pipes in the middle may fill up, blocking the entire pipeline.

I'm going to point you at [C Minishell — Adding Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636252/c-minishell-adding-pipelines) as a question with an answer showing how to do it.  It is not the only way of doing it, and I'm not convinced it is the best way to do it, but it does work.

Sorting this out in your code is left as an exercise — I need to get some work done now.  But this should give you strong pointers in the right direction.

Note that since your parent shell creates all the sub-processes, the `waitpid()` code is not ideal.  You will have zombie processes accumulating.  You'll need to think about a loop which collects any dead children, possibly with `WNOHANG` as part of the third argument so that when there are no zombies, the shell can continue.  This becomes even more important when you run processes in background pipelines, etc.